# Configuring resource in Tomcat's context.xml to access remote Weblogic JMS queues

Tags: jms, tomcat7, weblogic

What I intend to do is access remote queues in Oracle Weblogic JMS (version 10.3.4) from a spring application deployed in Tomcat7.

For this I am trying to configure a Resource (eg JMS connection factory, queues etc) in Tomcat's context.xml file. Then access this resource using jndi lookup in the spring configuration file and provide it to the necessary beans. I have already created connection factory and queues in Weblogic JMS and they can be accessed using jndi names.

I am able to make it work successfully when using ActiveMQ instead of Weblogic JMS. However with Weblogic JMS, I am facing an issue with configuring the Resource element. I am not sure what attributes to be used with Resource tag while connecting to Oracle Weblogic JMS.

When working with ActiveMQ the resource element config looks like below

```
 <Resource name="jms/MyConnectionFactory" auth="Container"
        type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
        factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
        description="JMS Queue Connection Factory"
        brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"  brokerName="MyActiveMqBroker"/>
```

I am struggling to find the configuration to be used with Oracle Weblogic JMS. I have gone through documentations to see how to do it but with no luck.

Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: I assume it will be something like `<Resource 
name="jms/MyConnectionFactory" 
auth="Container" 
type="weblogic.jms.ConnectionFactory" 
factory="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"  brokerName="MyActiveMqBroker"/>`  Getting the factories correct being the key